# Creating functions that take a variable number of arguments

Tags: php, function, arguments

IN O'reilly Cookbook 3d edition there is an example:
(page 165 (189 on e-reader))

```
<?php

function mean() {
    $sum = 0;

    $size = func_num_args();

    foreach (func_get_args() as $arg) {
        $sum += $arg;

        $average = $sum / $size;

        return $average;
    }
}
$mean = mean(96, 93, 98, 98);
echo $mean;


?>
```

The mean should be 96,25 but the echo result is 24 ... what am i doing wrong?

The other solution on the page before gives a good result though:

```
function sean($numbers){
    $sum = 0;
    $size = count($numbers);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        $sum += $numbers[$i];

    }
$average = $sum / $size;

return $average;
}

$test = sean(array(96, 93, 98, 98));
echo $test;
```

Comment: You don't see any significant difference between the two loops...?

Comment: i do, it is stated in the book. 2nd example (first one i wrote here) is: accessing function parameters without using argument list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're `return`ing in the first iteration of the loop.
You need to average and `return` *after* the loop when *all* values have been summed.

Comment: you are correct. so there is/was a mistake in the book :)

Comment: If your first example is a straight copy of the book, then yes. It happens sometimes. They usually get reported or cleared up in newer additions. Also, the advantage of purchasing from O'Reilly website is that you can get updates to e-books for free, like when an error like this might be corrected.

Comment: You are right, it was a first edition of the book. I found some more mistakes in the examples of the book by the way. what I notice in general is: they expect you allready can program a littlebit. so they forget the part where they give the actual results. like with print_r, echo, or var_dump they expect you know how to get the final results yourself. while when as noob you test the code of the book, you end up with a blank screen :)